# I can't receive the new pubkey from tor through gpg

Tags: apt, gnupg, tor

I'm new to linux by about three weeks now, and I'm obviously still getting used to the system and it's basic commands.  One of the problems that I'm having is downloading the keys related to the Tor browser.

when I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` this is among the results:

> GPG error: https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 74A941BA219EC810

`gpg --list-key` returns not only the asymmetric sets that I created the other day when I was learning how to use gpg, but also returns a tor rsa set as well that's at the top of the list.  I've checked online for a solution to this problem but everything is between 4-8 years old and nothing seems to be working.

Thanks, yall

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://superuser.com/questions/513609/how-to-apt-update-when-apt-is-not-accepting-the-repository

Comment: Thanks. That link had everything that I needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)